# Including Mathematica code in a response

Tags: support

What is the best way to visually include Mathematica code in a response?

I am almost done writing one right now, and I'd like to include a small amount of code which shows a computation demonstrating a result I claim in the response.

**Edit.**

Here is art of what the code.  I realized that of I right clicked on the code and chose Copy As > MathML then I would pretty much get what I wanted (see below).  Is this the best I can do?  I mean, I guess the only more I could want is to have the text set in Courier so it looks more "code-ish."

Rx
   [
   θ_
   ]
  
  :=
  
   {
   
    
     {
     
      1
      ,
      0
      ,
      0
     
     }
    
    ,
    
     {
     
      0
      ,
      
       Cos
       [
       θ
       ]
      
      ,
      
       Sin
       [
       θ
       ]
      
     
     }
    
    ,
    
     {
     
      0
      ,
      
       -
       
        Sin
        [
        θ
        ]
       
      
      ,
      
       Cos
       [
       θ
       ]
      
     
     }
    
   
   }

Comment: Unfortunately this site doesn't have prettyprint/prettify enabled, otherwise you would be able to get the code highlighted like on [mathematica.se].

Comment: You could try writing it in a code block, start with three consecutive ticks "`" and end it with three consecutive ticks.

Answer (score 5):

The '{}' button at the top of the editor or pressing Control-k will indent a selected block by 4-spaces putting it in code block mode. Like this:

```
Rx[θ_] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {0, -Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}}
```

Comment: Yeah the only thing that bothers me about this is that in my code, I have used greek characters which I'm not sure how to deal with in the block mode.

Comment: Er...I'm unsure how to help with that. The [formatting sandbox](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/389/formatting-sandbox) will let you try out everything *except* MathJax in a place where people won't be bothered.

Comment: Ok...I might just use an image with a screenshot I suppose.

Comment: @josh I would suggest trying really hard to avoid including an image of text. (At least in a main-site question. If you're demonstrating a rendering problem on meta, it's fine.) Actually, I'm not sure I understand just what problem you're having. (In theory SE supports Unicode, including Greek letters) Maybe if you were to include a demonstration in your question, it'd be clearer?

Comment: @DavidZ I added an edit; hopefully the question is clearer now.

Comment: @josh hm, that should work. See the example I edited into dmckee's answer. (dmckee: hope you don't mind. I didn't think that one example would be appropriate material for a whole new answer.)

Comment: @DavidZ I'm perhaps being a bit dense here, but how did you typeset the theta character?

Comment: @josh I just copied and pasted from your question.

Comment: @joshphysics I think he used unicode. How you do that depends on your OS.

Comment: Oh yeah, that too. You can get a theta using the Alt+digits shortcuts or the Character Map on Windows, or by using a suitable alternate keyboard layout on any OS. But in this case copy+paste was the easiest way.

Comment: @DavidZ Ah ok thanks.

Comment: @joshphysics One trick I use is to type `&theta;` (when not on Windows) or `$\theta$` in the text box and copy the resultant character from the result.

Comment: @Manishearth Cool thanks.  Too bad we don't have prettification :(

Comment: @joshphysics: Use this for reference:       `αβγδΔΔεζηθϑΘι∫κλΛμvoπ∏ρσςτυφϕΦχψΨωΩ√∂∇∴∠∞⇔ℝℂ∅°(who uses degrees?.)×`

Answer (score 5):

The best option is to use the `{}` button, or `Ctrl + k`, to create four indenting spaces which will format code like

```
this,
```

as dmckee pointed out.

I would generally recommend **not** altering the Mathematica code. When posting any code on the site, it should be in a form that it will run directly after being copied and pasted.

Now, as it happens, Mathematica will automatically turn Greek ASCII characters, like `θ`, directly to their InputForm representation (i.e. `\[Theta]`) immediately upon pasting. It is therefore OK to change those characters to their ASCII representation. This is, in fact, what the [mathematica.se prettify userscript](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor) does.

More generally, though, you can't expect *all* your Mathematica code to be made completely clear. Take, for example, this piece of code,

```
Sound[{Play[Re[E^(-((10000 I)/(4 10^-6 I + 60 t)))/Sqrt[10^-6 - 15 I t]], {t, 0, 15}]}]
```

which I posted recently in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63798/slinky-reverb-the-origin-of-the-iconic-star-wars-blaster-sound). It lost quite a bit of formatting (fraction, square root, exponential) in the transcription process, but I can't put that in and **I definitely shouldn't do something that compromises the code upon copy-paste.** Thus I left it like that; if a clearer exposition of what the code is saying is necessary then I'd recommend adding a LaTeX'd version of what's going on.

Comment: If you don't like having stuff like `\[Theta]` floating around, it's quite easy to use the slash-dot operator and shove a different variable into the expression. Doesn't always work, though.

Comment: Symbols inside `\[ ... ]` will convert to their prettier versions automatically. More complicated formatting like the subscripts, radicals and fractions in my answer can be prettified by sandwiching them inside `StandardForm[Hold[ ... ]]` and copy-pasting the output.